# changing the fetch url according to the <option> of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

Im new to coding in general and trying out some projects to learn. I want to write a website that displays different Formula1 stats so i could learn about using api's.

I have a Dropdown menu in which all races of the current Season are displayed + the number of the race (first race being number 1). I want the Fetch URL to change depending on which  the user chooses

```
let roundsArray = []

fetch("https://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/11/results.json").then((data) =>{
  return data.json();
}).then((objectData)=>{

console.log(roundsArray);
let result = objectData.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].Results;
let race = objectData.MRData.RaceTable.Races[0].raceName;

document.getElementById('circuit').innerHTML = race;

let tableData="";
result.map((value)=>{
  tableData+=`
  <tr>
  <td>${value.position}</td>
  <td>${value.Driver.givenName + " " + value.Driver.familyName}</td>
  <td>${value.Constructor.name}</td>
  <td>${value.points}</td>
</tr>`;   
});
 document.getElementById("table_body").
 innerHTML=tableData;

});

fetch("https://ergast.com/api/f1/current.json").then((data) =>{
  return data.json();
}).then((objectData)=>{


  let races = objectData.MRData.RaceTable.Races;

  races.forEach(element => {
    let testing = { title: element.raceName, round: element.round }
     roundsArray.push(testing)
 });

 console.log(roundsArray);

  let menuData="";
  roundsArray.map((value)=>{
    menuData+=`
    <option>${value.round} - ${value.title}</option>
    `;
  });

  document.getElementById("chose").
  innerHTML=menuData;

});
```

i want the number after the year in the fetch url(in the code "11") to change to the value.round (in menudata). And have no idea how to go about doing that.
Also sorry for some probably very chaotic code

Comment: So add a select element. Add change event that calls a function. Read the value of the select. Build a string with the value. Make the fetch call.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the value in the select option once its selected into the url and then call the API on the new url

below comments in the code explains it more clearly

```js
function getSelectedUrl(){
  // get selected option
  var selectedOption = document.getElementById("RaceList").value;
  
  // put the selected option in the url and return it
  return `https://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/${selectedOption}/results.json`;
}

function getRace(){
  // call getSelectedUrl to get new url based in selected option
  var newUrl = getSelectedUrl();
  
  // call the API with the new url
  fetch(newUrl).then((data) =>{
    return data.json();
  }).then((objectData)=>{
    console.log(objectData);
  });
}

// When you select an option it will call getRace function
document.getElementById("RaceList").addEventListener("change", getRace);
```

```html
<select id="RaceList">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Okay thank you =) this would work nicely i think.. the problem is that the options in my code get added dynamically depending on how many races there are in a certain year/season.. i tried adding the value dynamically too (by just putting it as which race number it is) but it doesnt really work sadly

Comment: @Mentura it should work. I have read the API you put a bit and looked through different API they provide. Try it if you cant make it work put it in a different question on stack overflow